# I can glow and expand your mind - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I can glow and expand your mind.
I spend most of the time out of sight.
I am not animal nor plant. What am I?

Hint:

> You can eat me, but sometimes I am dangerous for your health.

Hint 2:

> I can grow as large as a few kilometres.

Comment: This is a good start, but unfortunately it's a _little_ to broad.

Comment: I added another property which should help with the solution

Comment: I suspect (and hope) that although many things can fit the clues, only one is truly satisfying. For example, I'm pretty sure a rot13(tybj va gur qnex obbx) isn't the answer. ;)

Comment: I feel the answer is quite satisfying and it's not what you posted.

Comment: The hint is very descriptive rot13(Lbh pna rng nalguvat ohg gur erny dhrfgvba vf pna lbh rng vg gjvpr?)... (This is just a joke)

Comment: [Hints should not be required](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4561/69582) - if a puzzle is too broad without hints, it's still close-worthy

Comment: It's hard to predict the difficulty of a puzzle. I thought the first sentence was enough. But added the second one just to be sure. It wasn't enough so added a third and a hint.

Comment: Difficulty is not the issue - the problem is if it's too easy to find an answer that fits, that is, if the puzzle isn't constrained enough to have a single answer.

Comment: The answers here are good, but they don't truly match all the constraints. I feel that the answer I have fits everything perfectly.

Comment: guys you can close it. Pity though as the answer is beautiful

Comment: So I told my wife the first sentence of this puzzle and she found the answer in 5 seconds. She is not into puzzles too. So I feel you guys are really overthinking it.

Comment: The answer may be beautiful, but the riddle you have constructed around it is rickety at best. I get your intended answer, but if you ever feel the need to comment "Good answer, but not what I was looking for", you must be on shrooms if you think you've been specific enough.

Comment: That's the best comment ever! And correct :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> MAGNESIUM?

I can glow

> According to [this](https://cen.acs.org/education/Chemistry-Pictures-Blinded-magnesium/97/web/2019/04#:%7E:text=When%20magnesium%20reacts%20with%20oxygen,powdery%20magnesium%20oxide%20(MgO).), "When magnesium reacts with oxygen, it produces light bright enough to blind you temporarily". The luster of magnesium itself is sometimes referred to as a glow.

and expand your mind.

> Many take magnesium supplements specifically for improving brain health

I spend most of the time out of sight.

> As a metal, it is often underground

I am not animal nor plant. What am I?

> You are not an animal or a plant, you are MAGNESIUM?

Hint:

You can eat me, but sometimes I am dangerous for your health.

> It's found in foods, but overdosing can make you quite sick.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Neuron?

> Neurons can glow (emit light) and expand your mind (create more connections etc) and are
>  mostly out of sight.

Comment: Good answer, but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the intended answer.

But I suddenly got this

> **IDEA !**

So, it can expand your mind and it is not always visible as well. And how does it glow? Please take a look at this.

> [image]

Comment: A great attempt, but not the answer. I guess it is never visible, rather than "most of the time".